# two dimensional input in neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to feed a cell containing of two dimensional inputs to the neural network in matlab. the input is a graph which is shown in a two dimensional matrix (n*n). how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your neural network is 2D, subsequently your input is 1D, which means you will have to give a vector. In your case, this latter would be n²-sized.

Comment: thanks for your help. but I have 100 inputs for training, each consist of 13*13 matrix. therefore each instance for training has two dimensions, (13*13). it means my input is a cell of 1*100 and each of 100, is a matrix of 13*13. I'd be thankful if you help. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just string your whole input out as a one-dimensional array:

```
input_vec = reshape(input_mat, length(input_mat)^2, 1);  % assuming your input_mat is square
```

So rather than having a 10x10 (or whatever) matrix input to your network, you would have a 100x1 vector being input. Then train your network on this vector. This approach is commonly used in textbook character recognition networks, for example read [the section titled The MNIST Data in this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).